# Whats the simplest way to run my program for one minute then pause it for one minute

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, while-loop

I have some code here that prints a line one time every minute but I want to change it so it prints the message for one minute straight then pauses for one minute indefinitely. How do I achieve this?

```
 import time
 while True:
     print("This prints once a minute.")
     time.sleep(60) # Delay for 1 minute (60 seconds).
```

Comment: By "prints the message for one minute straight" do you mean prints once every second?

Comment: Use cron or your os scheduler

Comment: Have you done any research? I believe questions like this have been asked many times already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the message constantly for a minute, then wait for a minute, then repeat indefinitely, you can use the following:

```
import time
while True:
    s = time.time()
    while time.time() < s + 60:
        print("Message")
    time.sleep(60)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the message every second for one minute. You can do something like below:

```
import time
original_time = time.time()
while time.time() < original_time + 60:
    print("This prints every second for one minute")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can track when you start your minute, and then wait 60 seconds. Each 60 seconds you switch the state of is_printing.

```
import time

is_printing = False
while True:
    is_printing = not is_printing
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time < 60:
        if is_printing:
            print("Printing this for a minute.")
```